# Liferay 7.2- Spring MVC Porltlet: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.liferay.portletmvc4spring.ViewRendererServlet Problem when deployment

Tags: spring, liferay, liferay-7, spring-portlet-mvc

I implemented a Liferay 7.2 portletmvc4spring module, I followed this tutorial https://github.com/liferay/portletmvc4spring/blob/master/README.md but I have a problem when deploying this portlet to Lr7.2 instance ( i searched in google but I didn't found a concrete solution ) maybe some one had the same issue in the past and could help maybe...

The problem is the following :

> 2020-01-06 20:36:43.468 ERROR
>   [fileinstall-/usr/share/portail/liferay-portal-7.2.0-ga1/osgi/war][WebXMLDefinitionLoader:1130]
>   baseLr7Portlet_1.0.0 [1148] una java.lang.ClassCastException: class
>   com.liferay.portletmvc4spring.ViewRendererServlet
>
> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.liferay.portletmvc4spring.DispatcherPortlet cannot be cast to javax.portlet.Portlet

The full trace is the following :

> 2020-01-06 20:36:13.337 INFO 
>   [fileinstall-/usr/share/portail/liferay-portal-7.2.0-ga1/osgi/war][BaseAutoDeployListener:43]
>   Copying portlets for /usr/share/peLr7Portlet.war 2020-01-06
>   20:36:13.378 INFO 
>   [fileinstall-/usr/share/portail/liferay-portal-7.2.0-ga1/osgi/war][BaseDeployer:877]
>   Deploying baseLr7Portlet.war   Warning: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF modified
>   in the future.   Warning:
>   META-INF/maven/com.company.portail/baseLr7Portlet/pom.properties
>   modified in the future.   Warning:
>   META-INF/maven/com.company.portail/baseLr7Portlet/pom.xml modified in
>   the future.   Warning: WEB-INF/classes/ValidationMessages.properties
>   modified in the future.   Warning:
>   WEB-INF/classes/com/company/portail/demo/applicant/ApplicantPortlet.class
>   modified in the future.   Warning:
>   WEB-INF/classes/com/company/portail/demo/configuration/ContactConfiguration.class
>   modified in the future.   Warning:
>   WEB-INF/classes/com/company/portail/demo/configuration/ContactLanguage.class
>   modified in the future.   Warning:
>   WEB-INF/classes/com/company/portail/demo/controller/DemandeContactController.class
>   modified in the future.   Warning:
>   WEB-INF/classes/content/language.properties modified in the future.
>   Warning: WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties modified in the future.
>   Warning: WEB-INF/lib/Pportlet-api-3.0.0.jar modified in the future.
>   Warning: WEB-INF/lib/api-model-3.6.4.jar modified in the future.
>   Warning: WEB-INF/lib/cdi-api-1.2.jar modified in the future.
>   Warning: WEB-INF/lib/com.liferay.portletmvc4spring.framework-5.2.0.jar
>   modified in the future.   Warning:
>   WEB-INF/lib/com.liferay.portletmvc4spring.security-5.2.0.jar modified
>   in the future.   Warning: WEB-INF/lib/javax.el-api-3.0.0.jar modified
>   in the future.   Warning: WEB-INF/lib/javax.interceptor-api-1.2.jar
>   modified in the future.   Warning:
>   WEB-INF/lib/portail-common-3.6.4.jar modified in the future.
>   Warning: WEB-INF/lib/portlet-servlet-adapter-3.1.0.jar modified in the
>   future.   Warning: WEB-INF/liferay-plugin-package.properties modified
>   in the future.   Warning:
>   WEB-INF/spring-context/portlet-application-context.xml modified in the
>   future.   Warning: WEB-INF/spring-context/portlet/portlet1-context.xml
>   modified in the future.   Warning: WEB-INF/classes/com modified in the
>   future.   Warning: WEB-INF/classes/com/company modified in the
>   future.   Warning:
>   WEB-INF/classes/com/company/portail/demo/configuration modified in
>   the future.   Warning: WEB-INF/spring-context modified in the future. 
>   Warning: images modified in the future. 2020-01-06 20:36:14.440 INFO 
>   [fileinstall-/usr/share/portail/liferay-portal-7.2.0-ga1/osgi/war][BaseAutoDeployListener:50]
>   Portlets for /usr/share/portail/llet.war copied successfully
>   2020-01-06 20:36:43.468 ERROR
>   [fileinstall-/usr/share/portail/liferay-portal-7.2.0-ga1/osgi/war][WebXMLDefinitionLoader:1130]
>   baseLr7Portlet_1.0.0 [1148] una java.lang.ClassCastException: class
>   com.liferay.portletmvc4spring.ViewRendererServlet
>           at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3404)
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.context.helper.internal.definition.WebXMLDefinitionLoader._getServletInstance(WebXMLDefinitionLoader.java:1124
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.context.helper.internal.definition.WebXMLDefinitionLoader._setServlet(WebXMLDefinitionLoader.java:1164)
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.context.helper.internal.definition.WebXMLDefinitionLoader.endElement(WebXMLDefinitionLoader.java:353)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2967)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.context.helper.internal.definition.WebXMLDefinitionLoader.loadWebXMLDefinition(WebXMLDefinitionLoader.java:520
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.context.helper.internal.definition.WebXMLDefinitionLoader.loadWebXML(WebXMLDefinitionLoader.java:456)
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.context.helper.internal.ServletContextHelperRegistrationImpl.(ServletContextHelperRegistrationImpl.java:
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.context.helper.internal.ServletContextHelperRegistrationServiceFactory.getService(ServletContextHelperRegistra
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.servlet.context.helper.internal.ServletContextHelperRegistrationServiceFactory.getService(ServletContextHelperRegistra
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceFactoryUse$1.run(ServiceFactoryUse.java:212)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceFactoryUse.factoryGetService(ServiceFactoryUse.java:210)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceFactoryUse.getService(ServiceFactoryUse.java:111)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceConsumer$2.getService(ServiceConsumer.java:45)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.getService(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:524)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.getService(ServiceRegistry.java:464)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.getService(BundleContextImpl.java:624)
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WabBundleProcessor.initContext(WabBundleProcessor.java:456)
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WabBundleProcessor.init(WabBundleProcessor.java:136)
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WebBundleDeployer._initWabBundle(WebBundleDeployer.java:179)
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WebBundleDeployer.doStart(WebBundleDeployer.java:101)
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WabFactory$WABExtension.start(WabFactory.java:114)
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WabFactory.addingBundle(WabFactory.java:67)
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WabFactory.addingBundle(WabFactory.java:49)
>           at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:475)
>           at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:1)
>           at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
>           at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:229)
>           at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:450)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:908)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:230)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:137)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:129)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:191)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:578)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:428)
>           at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1264)
>           at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1237)
>           at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.doProcess(DirectoryWatcher.java:520)
>           at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:365)
>           at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:316)
>   2020-01-06 20:43:26.926 ERROR
>   [fileinstall-/usr/share/portail/liferay-portal-7.2.0-ga1/osgi/war][PortletLocalServiceImpl:2567]
>   Filter mapping with filter name SpringSecurityPortletFilter references
>   unknown portlet name baseLr7Portlet 2020-01-06 20:43:26.946 WARN 
>   [fileinstall-/usr/share/portail/liferay-portal-7.2.0-ga1/osgi/war][PortletLocalServiceImpl:876]
>   Portlet with the name springDisptachar_WAR_baseLr7Portlet is described
>   in portlet.xml but does not have a matching entry in
>   liferay-portlet.xml 2020-01-06 20:43:26.946 WARN 
>   [fileinstall-/usr/share/portail/liferay-portal-7.2.0-ga1/osgi/war][PortletLocalServiceImpl:888]
>   Portlet with the name baseLr7Portlet_WAR_baseLr7Portlet is described
>   in liferay-portlet.xml but does not have a matching entry in
>   portlet.xml 2020-01-06 20:43:26.954 ERROR
>   [fileinstall-/usr/share/portail/liferay-portal-7.2.0-ga1/osgi/war][PortletLocalServiceImpl:930]
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.liferay.portletmvc4spring.DispatcherPortlet cannot be cast to
>   javax.portlet.Portlet java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.liferay.portletmvc4spring.DispatcherPortlet cannot be cast to
>   javax.portlet.Portlet
>           at com.liferay.portlet.PortletBagFactory._getPortletInstance(PortletBagFactory.java:295)
>           at com.liferay.portlet.PortletBagFactory.create(PortletBagFactory.java:106)
>           at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.PortletLocalServiceImpl.initWAR(PortletLocalServiceImpl.java:918)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.AopMethodInvocationImpl.proceed(AopMethodInvocationImpl.java:50)
>           at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.AopInvocationHandler.invoke(AopInvocationHandler.java:49)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy138.initWAR(Unknown Source)
>           at com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.PortletLocalServiceUtil.initWAR(PortletLocalServiceUtil.java:457)
>           at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.doInvokeDeploy(PortletHotDeployListener.java:228)
>           at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.PortletHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(PortletHotDeployListener.java:96)
>           at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.doFireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:232)
>           at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.HotDeployImpl.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployImpl.java:97)
>           at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil.fireDeployEvent(HotDeployUtil.java:27)
>           at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.fireDeployEvent(PluginContextListener.java:189)
>           at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.doPortalInit(PluginContextListener.java:179)
>           at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.portalInit(BasePortalLifecycle.java:44)
>           at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:75)
>           at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalLifecycleUtil.register(PortalLifecycleUtil.java:57)
>           at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.BasePortalLifecycle.registerPortalLifecycle(BasePortalLifecycle.java:54)
>           at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PluginContextListener.contextInitialized(PluginContextListener.java:141)
>           at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SecurePluginContextListener.contextInitialized(SecurePluginContextListener.java:152)
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.adapter.ServletContextListenerExceptionAdapter._initializeContext(ServletContextListenerExceptionAdapter.java:119)
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.adapter.ServletContextListenerExceptionAdapter.contextInitialized(ServletContextListenerExceptionAdapter.java:99)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor186.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.ListenerRegistration$EventListenerInvocationHandler.invoke(ListenerRegistration.java:143)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy932.contextInitialized(Unknown Source)
>           at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.context.ContextController.doAddListenerRegistration(ContextController.java:350)
>           at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.context.ContextController.addListenerRegistration(ContextController.java:303)
>           at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.customizer.ContextListenerTrackerCustomizer.addingService(ContextListenerTrackerCustomizer.java:67)
>           at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.customizer.ContextListenerTrackerCustomizer.addingService(ContextListenerTrackerCustomizer.java:1)
>           at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:943)
>           at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:1)
>           at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
>           at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:229)
>           at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:903)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:109)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:891)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:127)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:469)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:487)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:1004)
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WabBundleProcessor.initListeners(WabBundleProcessor.java:623)
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WabBundleProcessor.init(WabBundleProcessor.java:216)
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WebBundleDeployer._initWabBundle(WebBundleDeployer.java:179)
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WebBundleDeployer.doStart(WebBundleDeployer.java:101)
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WabFactory$WABExtension.start(WabFactory.java:114)
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WabFactory.addingBundle(WabFactory.java:67)
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WabFactory.addingBundle(WabFactory.java:49)
>           at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:475)
>           at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:1)
>           at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
>           at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:229)
>           at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:450)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:908)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:230)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:137)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:129)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:191)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:578)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:428)
>           at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1264)
>           at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1237)
>           at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.doProcess(DirectoryWatcher.java:520)
>           at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:365)
>           at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:316)
>   2020-01-06 20:43:27.023 INFO 
>   [fileinstall-/usr/share/portail/liferay-portal-7.2.0-ga1/osgi/war][PortletHotDeployListener:310]
>   0 portlets for baseLr7Portlet are available for use 2020-01-06
>   20:43:27.512 ERROR
>   [fileinstall-/usr/share/portail/liferay-portal-7.2.0-ga1/osgi/war][WabBundleProcessor:229]
>   Catastrophic initialization failure! Shutting down baseLr7Portlet WAB
>   due to: null java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy935.registerServlets(Unknown Source)
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WabBundleProcessor.init(WabBundleProcessor.java:222)
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WebBundleDeployer._initWabBundle(WebBundleDeployer.java:179)
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WebBundleDeployer.doStart(WebBundleDeployer.java:101)
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WabFactory$WABExtension.start(WabFactory.java:114)
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WabFactory.addingBundle(WabFactory.java:67)
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WabFactory.addingBundle(WabFactory.java:49)
>           at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:475)
>           at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:1)
>           at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
>           at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:229)
>           at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:450)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:908)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:230)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:137)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:129)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:191)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:578)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
>           at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:428)
>           at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1264)
>           at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1237)
>           at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.doProcess(DirectoryWatcher.java:520)
>           at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:365)
>           at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:316)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.adapter.ModifiableServletContextAdapter.invoke(ModifiableServletContextAdapter.java:447)
>           ... 28 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.adapter.ModifiableServletContextAdapter.addServlet(ModifiableServletContextAdapter.java:233)
>           at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.adapter.ModifiableServletContextAdapter.registerServlets(ModifiableServletContextAdapter.java:582)
>           ... 33 more 2020-01-06 20:43:27.549 INFO  [fileinstall-/usr/share/portail/liferay-portal-7.2.0-ga1/osgi/war][PortletHotDeployListener:408]
>   0 portlets for baseLr7Portlet were unregistered 2020-01-06
>   20:43:27.788 INFO 
>   [fileinstall-/usr/share/portail/liferay-portal-7.2.0-ga1/osgi/war][BundleStartStopLogger:39]
>   STARTED baseLr7Portlet_1.0.0 [1148]

This is my Portlet.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<portlet-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/portlet"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/portlet http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/portlet/portlet-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <portlet>
        <portlet-name>springDisptachar</portlet-name>
        <portlet-class>com.liferay.portletmvc4spring.DispatcherPortlet</portlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <name>contextConfigLocation</name>
            <value>/WEB-INF/spring-context/portlet/portlet1-context.xml</value>
        </init-param>
        <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
        <supports>
            <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
            <portlet-mode>view</portlet-mode>
            <portlet-mode>edit</portlet-mode>
            <portlet-mode>help</portlet-mode>
        </supports>
        <resource-bundle>content.language</resource-bundle>
        <portlet-preferences>
            <preference>
                <name>datePattern</name>
                <value>MM/dd/yyyy</value>
            </preference>
            <preference>
                <name>recipientEmailAddress</name>
                <value>email@test.fr</value>
            </preference>
        </portlet-preferences>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>administrator</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>guest</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>power-user</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
        <security-role-ref>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </security-role-ref>
    </portlet>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>SpringSecurityPortletFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.liferay.portletmvc4spring.security.SpringSecurityPortletFilter</filter-class>
        <lifecycle>ACTION_PHASE</lifecycle>
        <lifecycle>RENDER_PHASE</lifecycle>
        <lifecycle>RESOURCE_PHASE</lifecycle>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SpringSecurityPortletFilter</filter-name>
        <portlet-name>baseLr7Portlet</portlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
</portlet-app>
```

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks a lot ...
Regards

Answer (score 1):

In order to address problems like this, I find it helpful to start with a minimal portlet project that deploys and runs correctly. For example, I recommend that you start by generating a PortletMVC4Spring JSP project from the archetype:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=com.liferay.portletmvc4spring.archetype \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=com.liferay.portletmvc4spring.archetype.form.jsp.portlet \
    -DarchetypeVersion=5.2.0 \
    -DgroupId=com.mycompany \
    -DartifactId=com.mycompany.my.form.jsp.portlet
```

Then, gradually add dependencies and/or features one-at-a-time, re-deploying after each change, until the problem occurs.

One thing I noticed is that your portlet WAR contains some dependencies in WEB-INF/lib that probably shouldn't be there. For example:

- WEB-INF/lib/cdi-api-1.2.jar
- WEB-INF/lib/javax.el-api-3.0.0.jar
- WEB-INF/lib/javax.interceptor-api-1.2.jar

The CDI API jar is especially concerning, since CDI and Spring are almost always mutually exclusive.

Comment: Great Idea Neil, I will go step by step by adding each time new feature/dependency and deploy it to the tomcat server, i'm sur it i can catch the problem like that (nice logic ) also I will try to remove the uncessary dependency like you mention.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens in different situations. One possible case is that you have multiple `*.jar` file implementing Interface `Portlet.java`. When I faced this problem, I removed all deployed plugins from my application server (`webapps` of `Tomcat` in my system) and revised `liferay-plugin-package.properties` so I left only those `jar`s in `portal.dependency.jars` that were necessary and removed the others. Then I deployed the plugin again and the problem was resolved.

Comment: Hello Abdollah,
Thank you for the reply..
Please Where can I find the portal.dependency.jars so that I know which jars needs to be left ?
another thing my liferay-plugin-package.properties only contains things like that liferay-versions=7.2.*
long-description=
module-group-id=liferay
module-incremental-version=1 , doesn't contain jars

Comment: Hello. You're welcome. It seems that your plugin.package.properties doesn't contain `portal.dependency.jars`. Please have a look at this article: https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-0/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/resolving-a-plugins-dependencies that discusses dependency management in LR 7.